# Is it possible to enlarge Ubuntu desktop somehow

Tags: compiz, multiple-monitors, resolution, display

Is it possible to enlarge Ubuntu Desktop in a way that screen resolution was more than real resolution of display.
I mean for example if I have monitor 1024x768, but I want to set resolution wider and taller: 1200x800 (as example). 
That would be great if this screen look and act like Compiz Enhanced Zoom Desktop. I mean when you move cursor to the corner-you can see what is in this corner.

Maybe someone know such application or settings, cause i'm not satisfied about my display resolution and can't add another display..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called panning viewport. X has supported this for many years, it was awesome with low resolution monitors and it works exactly as you described.

I haven't tried it with recent version of Ubuntu, so I'll better point you to the [official documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Panning_viewport).

It's done with `xrandr --panning`, but be sure to read everything before experimenting with your resolutions.

Comment: Thanks! That almost perfect! Also would be great if mouse tracking work like in Compiz Enhanced Zoom. But seems I want too much.. :)

Comment: Panning viewport acts as compiz enhanced zoom: the screen becomes a viewport of your bigger virtual desktop, and the viewport automatically follows the cursor. I'd bet the compiz plugin was modelled after it.
I'm sorry to comment so late, I hope you got it working by now.

Comment: I meant that panning viewport and compiz enhanced zoom act slightly different: in panning viewport when cursor comes near the border of screen - screen moves with a cursor; in compiz enhanced zoom if cursor is even in a center of screen and you move it - screem moves too. That's more convenient for me a bit. But not so important :)

Answer (score -1):

my understanding was that the max resolution was the same as the physical amount pf pixels on the display, so the reason why you cant get a higher res is because everything would be downscaled and certain pixels would be skipped, eg you could just have a like through an icon chopped out because it simply doesnt have enough pixels.

its also a measurement of how far your Graphics card can really push itself, i know that mac displays can go so high because they have a very high PPI (pixels per inch)

sorry if the answer is wrong, if you do manage to do it please comment on this as i would love to do it myself as i have tried and failed haha

Comment: Seems that my question is not very clear. Well, I hope it's clear for those who used Compiz Enhanced Zoom at once. ASalazar understood what I ment :) I'll check his proposal. Any way thank you for reply :)

Comment: The only limit is how much video RAM your card has. A decade ago I could use a 800x600 laptop screen with a virtual desktop of 1024x768. The trick was using fewer colors to free up video memory. It was one of the things that made me realize *nix was uglier but actually technologically superior.